# Rails GraphQL nested mutation/query structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I need some way to structurize GraphQL API in Rails.
I see that most developers do big chain of GraphQL queries and mutation like

```
{
  mutation {
    updateProfile(firstName: "Luke", lastname: "Skywalker") {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  mutation {
    deleteProfile()
  }
}
```

etc.

I'd like to have something like namespaces. Example

For example

```
{
  mutation {
   me {
     profile {
       update(firstName: "Luke", lastname: "Skywalker") {
         id
         firstName
         lastName
       }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Thank u all for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is something that is not permitted by the GraphQL Specification (https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/).